# Window placement of new shell buffer

Tags: window

Opening a new *shell* buffer takes over any window other than the one I type the command into.

What variable changes this behavior?  I have a guess the choices will be the same as these:

```
Hide Erc Join Buffer: Value Menu Bury in new buffer
    State : CHANGED outside Customize.
   Determines how to display a newly created IRC buffer. Hide

   The available choices are:

     ‘window’          - in another window,
     ‘window-noselect’ - in another window, but don’t select that one,
     ‘frame’           - in another frame,
     ‘bury’            - bury it in a new buffer,
     ‘buffer’          - in place of the current buffer,
     any other value  - in place of the current buffer.
Groups: Erc Buffers
```

That variable is `erc-join-buffer`.  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `display-buffer-alist`.